# which better mysql group count or count

Tags: mysql, count

multi select

```
select count(id) from table where name='a'
select count(id) from table where name='b'
```

one select with group

```
select name,count(id) from table where name in('a','b') group by name;
```

which one is better?

Comment: Please don't use MYSQL. Use **MYSQLi** or **PDO** instead

Answer (score 1):

I say the group by statement in such a simple example would perform equal or better, and probably better because if you're running two different select statements that you need to group, there is going to be a hit in performance to post process your information as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's better to prepare and execute one SQL statement rather than two statements.

It's "better" in terms of resources, due to the overhead involved with sending the statement to the MySQL server, the MySQL server parsing the statement, preparing the execution plan, and then executing the plan, then returning the resultset. On the client side, there's a bit of housekeeping overhead too.

While it won't make any much difference on the overall response time for the app for a single request, the real issue is scalability on the MySQL server.

On the other hand, if the single statement is considerably more resource intensive than two separate statements, then running two separate statements is preferred.

In your case, absent any information about the schema and the row distribution, it's very likely that the one statement that gets both counts is the "better" way to go.

(There is the issue with the one statement that it may return zero, one or two rows; while the two individual statements will return 1 row each.  (So handling the resultset on the client side will be a little different.)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the second one with `GROUP` because you only need to execute once against the server.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use GROUP BY for such kind of situations, If you just want to use it for a specific name go for individual i.e, **1st one**.

But, If you want to get the count for all names You have to go for the **GROUP BY** because simplifies your code as well as the performance hit on the server.